# Updating to the latest ALSA release

Tags: sound, ppa, alsa

I would like to have the latest stable/dev release of **ALSA**.

Can I do this via **PPA**?

So, I need a solution for stable versions and another one for latest releases, even they are unstable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a HDA Intel sound card, you can update to the latest ALSA release by following [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS) guide, or going to [this ppa](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/+packages) and downloading the one for your Ubuntu version.

Adding the PPA to your sources is not advised, because it will try to update ALSA every second day.